# Formatting dates in org mode

Tags: org-mode

How do I format dates in emacs org-mode?

For example, in the following table, I would like the dates to appear as "Aug 29", or "Wed, Aug 29" rather than "<2012-08-29 Wed>"

```
#+ATTR_HTML: border="2" rules="all" frame="border" align="center" cellpadding="6"
|------+------------------+---------+-------|
| Week | Date             | Speaker | Title |
|------+------------------+---------+-------|
|    / | <>               | <>      | <>    |
|    0 | <2012-08-29 Wed> |         |       |
|    2 | <2012-09-05 Wed> |         |       |
|    3 | <2012-09-12 Wed> |         |       |
|    1 | <2012-09-19 Wed> |         |       |
|    4 | <2012-09-26 Wed> |         |       |
|    5 | <2012-10-03 Wed> |         |       |
|    6 | <2012-10-10 Wed> |         |       |
|    7 | <2012-10-17 Wed> |         |       |
|    8 | <2012-10-24 Wed> |         |       |
|    9 | <2012-10-31 Wed> |         |       |
|   10 | <2013-03-07 Thu> |         |       |
|------+------------------+---------+-------|
#+TBLFM: @3$1 = 0::$1 = @-1$1 + 1 ::@3$2 = <Aug 29, 2012>::$2 = @-1$2 + 7
```

Comment: I don't think you can trivially transform the dates into text representation. You can try using calc or custom elisp in table formulae to format the dates in another column.

Comment: @suvayu: Thanks! Is there a way to ignore a column when exporting as html?

Comment: I don't think there are any straight forward ways of doing this. The only way I can think of is to have two tables and use [remote references](http://orgmode.org/manual/References.html#References). You can use one table under a `COMMENT` headline to "feed" all your exported tables using remote references.

Answer (score 3):

[Custom date format](http://orgmode.org/manual/Custom-time-format.html) should help. It will show timestamps with your own custom formatting.

Comment: That will not work; custom dates are just in buffer overlays. AFAIK, it has no effect whatsoever during export.

Comment: Custom date format does affect export. Just try a minimal example, toggle custom format with `C-c C-x C-t` and export to browser with `C-c C-e b`.

Comment: Ah, it seems to work. I didn't expect in-buffer overlays to affect export! Thanks for correcting me.